# UIProgressView No Longer Updating After Draw Method Override

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am making a custom `UIProgressView` that will end up having drawn-on indicators, so naturally I did an override of the `Draw` method. However, I noticed that after the override was put in place, the `SetProgress` method that used to increment and decrement the progress bar no longer updates even though the `Draw` method is called.

Custom Class:

```
public class ModifiedProgressBar : UIProgressView
{
    public ModifiedProgressBar(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
    }
}
```

Called By:

```
private void UpdateDisplay(float step)
{
    this.modifiedProgressBar.SetProgress(step);
}
```

`UpdateDisplay` is then called by increment/decrement buttons. This code works perfectly fine against a `UIProgressView` class as well as the `ModifiedProgressBar` class without the `Draw` override put in place. The `Progress` property also updates with the new set values, the view just does not update. I have tried calling `SetNeedsDisplay` which has not forced the view to update. What is happening under the covers here and is there a way to allow this to properly draw? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will actually need to supply your drawing routine, not call the base, and of course alter your drawing based upon the `Progress` property.

Something as simple as a yellow rectangle:

[image]

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    var color = UIColor.FromRGBA(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.000f);
    var rectanglePath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(new CGRect(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width * Progress, rect.Height));
    color.SetFill();
    rectanglePath.Fill();
}
```

Or a red pointy thingie™:

[image]

```
public override void Draw(CGRect frame)
{
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    var color2 = UIColor.FromRGBA(0.199f, 0.018f, 0.018f, 1.000f);
    var shadow = new NSShadow();
    shadow.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black;
    shadow.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(3.1f, 3.1f);
    shadow.ShadowBlurRadius = 5.0f;
    UIBezierPath bezierPath = new UIBezierPath();
    bezierPath.MoveTo(new CGPoint(frame.GetMinX() + 0.00935f * frame.Width * Progress, frame.GetMinY() + 0.01351f * frame.Height));
    bezierPath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(frame.GetMinX() + 0.99537f * frame.Width * Progress, frame.GetMinY() + 0.50000f * frame.Height));
    bezierPath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(frame.GetMinX() + 0.99537f * frame.Width * Progress, frame.GetMinY() + 0.50000f * frame.Height));
    bezierPath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(frame.GetMinX() + 0.00935f * frame.Width * Progress, frame.GetMinY() + 0.98570f * frame.Height));
    bezierPath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(frame.GetMinX() + 0.00935f * frame.Width * Progress, frame.GetMinY() + 0.01351f * frame.Height));
    bezierPath.ClosePath();
    bezierPath.LineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Square;
    bezierPath.LineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.Bevel;
    context.SaveState();
    context.SetShadow(shadow.ShadowOffset, shadow.ShadowBlurRadius, shadow.ShadowColor.CGColor);
    UIColor.Red.SetFill();
    bezierPath.Fill();
    context.RestoreState();
    color2.SetStroke();
    bezierPath.LineWidth = 1.0f;
    bezierPath.Stroke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it looks like this wasn't the best way to tackle my issue. Since I did not want to lose functionality of a standard `UIProgressView`, I instead wrote my own custom class inheriting from a `UIView` and drew it over the currently existing `UIProgressView` in the application. Your detailed answer helped me understand what happens under the covers when the draw method is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

`UIProgressView` uses a series of `UIImageView` objects and stretches their bounds rectangle to make the progress grow. `UIImageView` does not respond to `drawRect:rect`:

> Do not use image views for custom drawing. The UIImageView class does not draw its content using the drawRect: method. Use image views only to present images. https://apple.co/2HIGtOx

The regular use for `UIProgessView` is to create an `NSProgress` object (say `prog`) for the semantic layer, give the view layer's `UIProgressView` based object (say `progView`) the `NSProgress` object by setting the observedProgress (https://apple.co/2vORFoh)

In short:

`progView.observedProgress = prog;`

Then in the semantic layer:

`prog.completedUnitCount += 1;`

which tracks your progress in the semantic operations and magically updates the view's progView (that is "observing") at the same time. This is the single biggest reason I wanted to use UIProgressView as a base class.

I talked with the Apple engineers in the UI lab at WWDC 2018 about this exact topic last week.  Their feedback was:

1. UIProgressView was not designed to be subclassed and as such is
   not supported (they may break your code), just
2. create a UIView and draw your progress indicator into that and
3. use Key Value Observing to isolate the interface code from the semantic code.

A couple of examples I checked out in GitHub (in Swift):

[image: circular progress]

- https://github.com/iwasrobbed/RPCircularProgress
- https://github.com/Eclair/CircleProgressBar